# Database Driven Model Mapping in Java

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, mapping, orika

So, I have a project where I get data from a dozen different sources, some are database objects, most often the data is in different JSON formats, or often XML formats.  So, I need to take this disparate data and pull it into one single clean managed object that we control.

I have seen dozens of different posts on various tools to do object to object mapping.   Orika being one of them, etc.   But the problem is that Orika, like many of these still need solid classes defined to do the mapping.   If there is a change to the mapping, then I have to change my class, re-commit it, then do a build and deploy new code ... BTW, testing would also have to be done like any code change.   So, maybe some of these tools aren't a great solution for me.

Then I was looking to do some sort of database-driven mapping, where I have a source, a field, and then the new field or function I would like to take it to.  So, with a database-driven tool, I could modify the fields in the database, and everything would keep working as it should.  I could always create a front-end to modify this tool.

So, with that ... I am asking if there is any database-driven tool where I can map field to field, or fields to functions type of mapping?   Drools was my first choice, but I don't know if it is my best choice?   Maybe it is overkill for my needs?   So, I was looking for advice on what might be the best tool to do my mapping.

Please let me know if you need any more information from me, and thanks for all the help!

Comment: Whether mapping is done via application code or via some database driven tool -- a QA iteration should be necessary to avoid any potential data entry problems.  Personally an external tool to do this via a database just creates technical debt that could be avoided by self documenting code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Orika can handle dynamic Data source like that, there is even an example on how to convert from XML Element (DOM API) or even JsonObject.

You can use an XML parser to convert your data into Element object, or Jackson to get JsonObject

Then define you class map between your "Canonical" Java Class and these dynamic "Classes"

http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/advanced-mappings.html Customizing the PropertyResolverStrategy

Here is an example of Orika mapping to MongoDB DBObject to Java Bean
https://gist.github.com/elaatifi/ade7321a1405c61ff8a9

However converting JSON is more straightforward than XML (the semantic of Attributes/Childs/Custom tags do not match with JavaBeans)